maven: `mvn clean package install`
I have used maven for many years and got a strange error that lead me to this strange question:
why mvn clean install IS NOT THE SAME AS mvn clean package install ?
it says in documentation that when you call the install phase all the previous required phases will be called.
Here is the example I have it is only a pom.xml file (so no need for anything else but this file to reproduce the issue)

mvn clean install --> SUCCESS
mvn clean package install --> FAILURE (the task jar:3.3.0:jar (default-jar)is executed a second time...)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>mdr-wiremock-shaded</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
      <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
      <version>2.31.0</version>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.slf4j</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.org.slf4j</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>




mvn clean install the more or less correct one or just use mvn verify but using mvn clean package install repeats several parts.. so just stuck to mvn clean verify or just  mvn verify... which Maven version, JDK version etc. you are using?

If you run mvn clean package install you will run most of the goals twice. Depending on whether these goals are idempotent, this may or may not result in a different result than mvn clean install.
In any case, mvn clean package install is NOT recommended.

even though it is not that clearly specified in the documentation is actually seems that it is "normal" that goals are called multiple times....
